# Batch file that renames files numerically not working

Tags: batch-file

I have a folder into which I do a print to file option and it saves my print job as a pcl file. The software I use to do the print to file names each file in following manner: GUID.XX.pcl where XX is a number.
Example:

```
{2E594442-FDF9-4992-88DA-EA4ED2811ECD}.6.pcl
{2E594442-FDF9-4992-88DA-EA4ED2811ECD}.7.pcl
{2E594442-FDF9-4992-88DA-EA4ED2811ECD}.8.pcl
{2E594442-FDF9-4992-88DA-EA4ED2811ECD}.9.pcl
{2E594442-FDF9-4992-88DA-EA4ED2811ECD}.10.pcl
{2E594442-FDF9-4992-88DA-EA4ED2811ECD}.11.pcl
```

What I want to do is rename the files so that they look like this:
1.pcl
2.pcl
3.pcl
and so on.

Here is the batch I use:

```
for %%a in (*.pcl) do (
    set /a i+=1
    ren "%%a" "!i!.new"
)
ren *.new *.pcl
```

This works but the problem is,in the example I gave above
It renames

```
{2E594442-FDF9-4992-88DA-EA4ED2811ECD}.10.pcl to 1.pcl
```

and

```
{2E594442-FDF9-4992-88DA-EA4ED2811ECD}.6.pcl to 3.pcl
```

I need it to rename

```
{2E594442-FDF9-4992-88DA-EA4ED2811ECD}.6.pcl to 1.pcl
```

and

```
{2E594442-FDF9-4992-88DA-EA4ED2811ECD}.10.pcl to 5.pcl
```

It is basically seeing 10 before 6. Is there some way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=." %%a in ('dir /B *.pcl') do (
   set /A num=100+%%b
   set "name[!num:~1!]=%%a.%%b.%%c"
)

for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('set name[') do (
   set /A i+=1
   ren "%%a" "!i!.pcl"
)
```

If you want to use two digits in the new name, so the order be preserved in `dir` or `for` listings, modify the second part this way:

```
set i=100
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('set name[') do (
   set /A i+=1
   ren "%%a" "!i:~1!.pcl"
)
```

**EDIT**: I tested my code and it works correctly. This is the output of the test session:

```
C:\> dir /b
test.bat
{2E594442-FDF9-4992-88DA-EA4ED2811ECD}.10.pcl
{2E594442-FDF9-4992-88DA-EA4ED2811ECD}.11.pcl
{2E594442-FDF9-4992-88DA-EA4ED2811ECD}.6.pcl
{2E594442-FDF9-4992-88DA-EA4ED2811ECD}.7.pcl
{2E594442-FDF9-4992-88DA-EA4ED2811ECD}.8.pcl
{2E594442-FDF9-4992-88DA-EA4ED2811ECD}.9.pcl

C:\> test

C:\> dir /b
1.pcl
2.pcl
3.pcl
4.pcl
5.pcl
6.pcl
test.bat

C:\> type test.bat
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=." %%a in ('dir /B *.pcl') do (
   set /A num=100+%%b
   set "name[!num:~1!]=%%a.%%b.%%c"
)

for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('set name[') do (
   set /A i+=1
   ren "%%a" "!i!.pcl"
)
```

Comment: Don't forget to start the script with `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` and `set i=0`.

Comment: I get an error "system cant find file specified" using the above. I did set delayed expansion. For the first FOR, i get                                            C:\>(
set /A num=100+10
 set "name[!num:~1!]={2E594442-FDF9-4992-88DA-EA4ED2811ECD}.10.pcl"
)                                                                                                                and the second FOR then gives                                                            C:\>(
set /A i+=1
 ren "{2E594442-FDF9-4992-88DA-EA4ED2811ECD}.10.pcl" "!i:~1!.pcl"
)
The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: I just realized that you used `ren "%%a" "!i:~1!.pcl"` part that does NOT appear in the original code! If you want to use the `"!i:~1!.pcl"` part, you must include `set 1=100` _before_ the second `for` as I indicated in my original answer.

Comment: Ok. I see what I did. How does the code change if I run the batch from a different folder than where the pcl files are? My pcl's are in c:\delivery and the batch will be in c:\batch

Comment: Include a `cd c:\delivery` command before the first `for`. PS - I don't understand how is possible that npocmaka's code can correctly rename the files! **`:/`**

Answer (score 0):

not tested:

```
for  %%a in (*.pcl) do (
    for /f "tokens=2 delims=}" %%# in ("%%~nxa") do (
        ren "%%~fa" "%%#"
    )
)
```

Comment: Instead of _dynamic_ `for  %%a in (*.pcl) do (` (as renamed files could _return_ to the `for` loop again) use either `for  %%a in ({*.pcl) do (` or _static_ `for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B *.pcl') do (` rather

Comment: this gives me a result of .6.pcl any idea how I can remove the leading period?